# Does setting importance = true on randomforest function build a different model

Tags: r, random-forest

I have been trying to build a model based on random forest, and have the made the model deterministic by setting the seed before calling randomForest function. After I get the random forest model, I created predictions for the model. The prediction values are different between when importance is set as true and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we set the randomForest method to calculate importance, the code to calculate importance calls up the random number generator to generate a random number, thus changing the sequence in which the random number generator is called. I set the seed, but the sequence has been changed, hence the difference in predictions.